# Backward navigation not working in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app using MVVM pattern, I want to do page navigation. I have written a code for that. And the forward page navigation works fine!

But the problem I am facing is that on back button press on a page, the app is quitting.

What I think the problem is that I am creating a new `_frame` object every time during page navigation, so because of that, the `_frame` object is not keeping the navigation history. The `_frame.CanGoBack` is giving `false` even after some rounds of navigation (It should be `true`).

So what am I missing here? How to keep the navigation history? Is anything wrong with my approach? I will appreciate any help.

The codes are as follows:

**NavigationService Class:**

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private readonly Frame _frame;

    public NavigationService()
    {
        _frame = new Frame();
    }

    public void NavigateTo(Type source)
    {
        Window.Current.Content = _frame;
        _frame.Navigate(source);
    }

    public void GoBack(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window.Current.Content = _frame;
        if (_frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            _frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }  
    }
}
```

**My XAML code behind:**

```
public INavigationService NavigationService;
public EmployeeProfilePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    ...
}
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService = new NavigationService();
    NavigationService.GoBack(this, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an new instance of Frame is wrong, just use the one frame created in App.xaml.cs

Just put _frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame to constructor and never use new Frame()

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `GoBack` on the current frame which can be accessed using the `Frame` property of the `Page` object. You also should have only one `Frame` for your app, which is instantiated on app launch.

```
    ...
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```